How can I find the locations of the tallest buildings in a given city?
I'm trying to find the location of a building in a city. All I know is that it's amongst the tallest buildings in the city. How can I find the locations of the tallest buildings in a given city?
Assume the city isn't on https://skyscraperpage.com/cities/maps, the city doesn't have a Wikipedia page listing the tallest buildings of that city and I'm not in that city so I can't look around.

Why was the question on finding the location of the tallest buildings in a given city closed as a question 'covering tasks performed by travel agent'?

4 possibilities come to mind:

Search the terms "city tallest buildings" with a search engine (even better if you can use one local to the country and use the localized search terms).
Call the city's office responsible for building permits or taxation, they likely have records tracking this kind of information. It will probably not be readily accessible, but if you're lucky they might be willing to help you find this (or be compelled to by some sort of law requiring them to provide information).
The country's aviation authority may publish lists or maps of obstructions important to aviation. Tall buildings have a good chance of being included.
Tall buildings often have antennas on top, some countries publish their licensed broadcast or radio facilities.


Check out any AI tool - GrokAI or ChatGPT for that very search.
I just tried it for a few major cities and was able to find an answer.
What cities are you looking for?

While I am not for AI use in many cases this is something they can give you a start on. Do not just trust their answers but double checking a few will be easier than checking all buildings in a whole city.

-1: Major cities is exactly not what this question is about, OP already linked to a page with those.
